# Instance variable is not available in cucumber steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Hi i am working on rails project where I have to test the API with Cucumber. i have some instance variables to store URL,token etc. My first scenario is working fine but my second scenario fails due to nil value of instance variables.

Feature file:

```
Feature: Bill Reminder

  Scenario: Validate POST bill_reminder API with valid parameters
    When I make POST bill_reminder API call
    Then It should return success for bill_reminder

  Scenario: Validate GET bill_reminder API with valid login token
    when I send a GET request to bill reminder details
    Then the json response should have title bill reminder
```

Steps File:

```
When(/^I make POST bill_reminder API call$/) do
  @url = 'http://example.com/api/bill_reminders'
  @params = {
              data: {
                type: "bill-reminders",
                attributes: {
                  title: "bill reminder",
                  all_day: "0",
                  start_date: "1409175049",
                  end_date: "1409175049"
                }
              }
            }
  @login_token = 'nev4hPOqyVCXGnOXLYPUhQ'
  @user_id = 402
end

Then(/^It should return success for bill_reminder$/) do
  header 'login_token', @login_token
  header 'user-id', @user_id
  response = post @url, @params

  response_body = JSON response.body
  @id = response_body['data']['id']
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
end

When(/^I send a GET request to bill reminder details$/) do
  @url = "http://example.com/api/bill_reminders/#{@id}"
  @user_id = 402
  @login_token = 'nev4hPOqyVCXGnOXLYPUhQ'
end

Then(/^the json response should have title bill reminder$/) do
  header 'login_token', @login_token
  header 'user-id', @user_id

  response = get @url
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
end
```

Here my second scenario "the json response should have title bill reminder" fails due to nil value of instance variables. I don't know why the value of instance variables is nil in the second scenario. Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In 2nd ***When*** step defination you have miss **underscore _** in method .

```
When(/^I send a GET request to bill_reminder details$/) do
  @url = "http://example.com/api/bill_reminders/#{@id}"
  @user_id = 402
  @login_token = 'nev4hPOqyVCXGnOXLYPUhQ'
end
```

Comment: Thanks actually the reason was "when I send a GET request to bill reminder details" 'w' is in small letter that's why it was not considering the when block.